# ExtJs 6-7 - Accordion panel click event on an item

Tags: extjs

How to catch the click event on an item in the accordion panel? I tried different options from the documentation, but nothing works

Comment: Do you mean the accordion's panel child panel header where you expand or collapse the panel, or an item within the expanded panel?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmrXT.png

Comment: You can listen to the events when a panel is expanded or collapsed, if it does solve your issue I can post an example in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved the problem myself. For the modern interface, the default panel is set, and listeners must be defined in it

```js
defaults: {
                titleCollapse: true,
                xtype: 'panel',
                animate: true,
                bodyPadding: 2,
                listeners: {
                    expand: function (panel, eOpts) {
                        console.log(panel.getTitle() + ' expanded.');
                    },
                    collapse: function (panel, eOpts) {
                        console.log(panel.getTitle() + ' collapsed.');
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Add `expand` / `collapse` listeners to the panel components inside the accordion panel, this is easier, but it is not exactly listening to the click event, rather to the state of the panel. It is also delayed a little bit if you use animation, because these events are fired when the animation is completed.
2. Add `click` listener to the panel's header. This is more precisely what you asked for, but there is a drawback: this way you override the default expand / collapse behaviour, and you need to take care of expanding / collapsing the panel.

The following code provides you with both examples, in **Ext JS 7.5.1 Classic Material**. Also see [fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3kvu), you can track the firing of events in console.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Accordion Panel',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            layout: {
                type: 'accordion',
                titleCollapse: true,
                animate: true,
                multi: true //false
            },
            defaults: {
                collapsed: true,
                // listen to click event on header
                header: {
                    listeners: {
                        click: function (header, e, eOpts ) {
                            const panel = header.up('panel');
                            console.log (panel.getTitle() + ' header clicked.');
                            if (panel.collapsed) {
                                panel.expand();
                            }
                            else {
                                panel.collapse();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                // listen to panel expand / collapse in accordion panel
                listeners: {
                    expand: function (panel, eOpts) {
                        console.log(panel.getTitle() + ' expanded.');
                    },
                    collapse: function (panel, eOpts) {
                        console.log(panel.getTitle() + ' collapsed.');
                    }
                }
            },
            items: [{
                title: 'Panel 1',
                html: 'Content 1',
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 2',
                html: 'Content 2',
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 3',
                html: 'Content 3',
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a modern version of Sencha
and your suggestion in listeners doesn't work

Comment: ```Ext.define('Admin.view.pages.Accordion', {
 xtype:'mainAccordion',
 extend: 'Ext.panel.Accordion',
    id:'panelAccordion',
    defaults: {
    titleCollapse: true,
    xtype: 'panel',
    bodyPadding: 2
    },
    openable: 1,
    items: items,
    listeners: {
       expand: function (panel, eOpts) {
        console.log(panel.getTitle() + ' expanded.');
       },
       collapse: function (panel, eOpts) {
        console.log(panel.getTitle() + ' collapsed.');
       }

      }
  
});```